Webi: Creating a calculated dimension?
I have a report with OrderIDs and related boolean dimensions for each order. I want to create a calculated dimension counting the boolean results for each dimension/object. Is this even possible in Webi or do I need to modify the universe?
I have a table with OrderID in rows and three columns that each give 0 or 1:

and I want to calculate it so that the columns give three rows and the columns count the number of OrderIDs with 0 and 1 for each:

Because the end users want it to look like this in the report:

Any suggestions how to do this?
I've tried running count but it doesn't work.
